# TYPO3 fluid: is it possible to write f:link.typolink inline?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x

I need something like this:

```
<f:link.typolink parameter="{link}">
     Linktext
</f:link.typolink>
```

but in inline syntax. Is this possible? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you have your linktext in a variable, you can write:

```
{linktext -> f:link.typolink(parameter: '1')}
```

if you want to set your linktext inside your fluidtemplate, you can:

```
{f:variable(name:'linktext', value:'My Linktext')}

{linktext -> f:link.typolink(parameter: '1')}
```

`parameter: 1` is a link to uid 1,
in your example you can use the `{link}` variable without the curly braces, e.g.:
`{f:link.typolink(parameter: link)}`

Answer (score 3):

There is an online converter to convert Fluid tags into inline notation:

http://www.fluid-converter.com/

**Update 27.09.2022:** The above mentioned URL is not valid anymore.
But there is a new tool: https://fluid-to-inline-converter.com/

Comment: I've added a new link to my answer.